Matthew 24: is "day and hour" an atomic expression?
Matthew 24

36“But concerning that day and hour no one knows, not even the angels
of heaven, nor the Son,b but the Father only


44Therefore you also must be ready, for the Son of Man is coming at an
hour you do not expect.
50the master of that servant will come on a day when he does not
expect him and at an hour he does not know

Matthew 25

13Watch therefore, for you know neither the day nor the hour.

When Jesus said day and hour, did he use it as:

An atomic expression - to emphasize the uncertainty of His coming
As two separate words ie no one can know the literal day nor the literal hour

I notice in the same context, he went on to only use hour. It does seem relevant given that He could've just used hour all 3 times.
Why this is relevant
Paul said the rapture will happen at the last trump which specifies both the day of Feast of Trumpets and the literal hour which is sunset.
If day and hour are two separate words and Jesus' words should be read as two separate words, then there is an very interesting tension here.
If day and hour is just an expression to emphasize the uncertainty, then it's less interesting.

"Paul said the rapture will happen at the last trump which specifies both the day of Feast of Trumpets and the literal hour which is sunset." — The "rapture" is a relatively recent term, long after Paul's time. He was referring to the transformation that occurs at Christ's return to Earth and the creation of the Kingdom of God. ¶ How do we know "last trump" refers to sunset?

@RayButterworth it refers to Feast of Trumpets. Paul doesn't define it which means his audience knows it. last trump means a sequence of trumpet blasts. This happens on Feast of Trumpets. Day of the Lord is: 24-hr/year/thousand. Thousand cannot fit in last 7 years. Isaiah 34 says day of the Lord is a year. 70th week of Daniel is a set of 7 years: 6 years work the land, 1 year rest. Same as 6 days creation, 1 day rest. 6 thousand years + millenium. The boundary of a year is Tishri 1, Feast of Trumpets. Daniel Walters' book 70x7

@ Maximus 1987 "Just an expression...less interesting...(?) This is a quite presumptuous, feckless assertion say the least!  That Christ would repeat this warning moves it far past "less interesting" on to an important, dire warning of utmost interest to those who take Jesus teaching seriously.

The simplest way to understand the phrase "day and hour" in Matt 24:26 and Mark 13:32 is as a merism for "exact time".  That is, Jesus is simply saying, in a rather forceful and emphatic way in both places, that no one knows the precise time of the second coming.
[As an aside, I note that nowhere does the Bible call Jesus' return or "parousia" παρουσία the "Rapture".]
Apart from the above two references alluding to Jesus return, there is only one other places that uses this language, but in an extended way, to denote the exact time, namely Rev 9:16, " ... this hour and day and month and year ... "

That matches my suspicion and but He then goes on to only use hour twice ... but then uses day and hour in the parable of the virgins! Can you elaborate or even speculate? I know nothing of Greek. Logically, I could imagine that it's a construct: having used day and hour, a normal person wouldn't repeat the same phrase. But then what about the virgin parable?

What's most confusing to me is that after he used just hour he then went back to using day and hour. I suppose it's possible there's no theological hint and He simply re-iterated day and hour because it's a grammatical structure: start with day and hour then use hour for however many examples then finish once again with day and hour. But this is all just speculation.

It may be useful to look at a parallel construction dealing with a similar issue in the Book of Acts 1:

6 When they had gathered together they asked him, “Lord, are you at
this time going to restore the kingdom to Israel?” 7 He answered
them, “It is not for you to know the times or seasons that the Father
has established by his own authority. 8 But you will receive power
when the holy Spirit comes upon you, and you will be my witnesses in
Jerusalem, throughout Judea and Samaria, and to the ends of the
earth.”

Times (chronos) are minutely measurable while seasons (kairos) are large units. So we have a direct parallel: we (including Jesus in Matthew) can know neither the general period, nor the specific moment.
Given this usage in Acts, I would lean toward Jesus' answer being a way of emphasizing uncertainty regarding the time rather than referring to specific periods such as days, hours, times and seasons.

I'm not entirely sure that is logically true. This was a response to a specific query: restoration of Israel. So, the primary meaning should be taken as the response to that question. Furthermore, in the same response He continues with a command to evangelize. Therefore, the primary point of Jesus' statement was focus on evangelization not with your head in the clouds.

Presumably, your mention of Paul saying "the rapture will happen at the last trump" refers to 1 Thessalonians 4:14-18. A detail - Paul never used the word 'rapture', for that comes from Latin for 'caught up'. Paul wrote in Greek and said 'caught up'. Nor did he say anything about the Feast of Trumpets at sunset. That is a matter of interpretation, but given his belief in Jesus speaking the truth about nobody knowing the day nor the hour when the resurrection would start, he would never indicate sunset on a Jewish feast day, would he?
Yes, 'day' and 'hour' are two separate words, but every day is made up of many hours. You cannot have a whole day without hours of daylight, and hours of darkness. The uncertainly lies in the fact that nobody knows which particular day Jesus will return, nor even what hour in that day the whole world will witness this spectacular event. The expression "day and hour" includes the idea of time, up until "when there shall be time no longer." - Revelation 10:6 (How interesting is that?)
The answer is that time (when spoken of in context of a day, and of hours) is both a measurable unit of time, and a way to emphasize that nobody can know beforehand when that day, nor when that hour will arrive. That is why Jesus told his followers to "watch and pray" that particular day of betrayal when, at a particular hour, his disciples would be caught napping. - Matthew 26:41 What good would it have done them to know in advance that day and to be wide awake throughout it, until just an hour before the event happened, when they had fallen asleep (again)?
The lesson for us who await Christ's unexpected return in glory to usher in the Day of Resurrection and Judgment is quite clear.

Your response doesn't address my question at a grammatical level.

And at the last trump is 1 Corin 15:52



Day of the Lord


DAY = 24 hours OR 1 year OR 1000 years


Isaiah 34 - day of Lord is 1 year


6+1


6 days creation, 1 day rest


6 days work, 1 day rest


6 thousand years + millenium


6 years farm land, 1 year rest


70 weeks of Daniel are a set of 7 years


6 years on earth followed by rapture and 1 year in heaven


Tishri 1 - sequence of Trumpet blasts and inaugurates new year



I note your comments, also that you never asked for the grammatical level to be explored. As demonstrated above, the OP seeks for interpretations to be given on a matter that runs throughout the whole Bible: how long is a prophetic hour, day, week or year? That would put the Q into the "Christianity" site, as it is a topic, not examination of 1 verse.

I placed the "greek" and "grammar" tag. And I asked if He used it as "atomic expression" or "as two separate words". What more could I have done? Uploaded a picture of myself winking?

Did you see the proof that "at the last trump" is the Feast of Trumpets? Rev 12 also places Jesus birth on Sep 11, 3 BC which is the Feast of Trumpets. So both "comings" will happen at The Feast of Trumpets.

And your analysis is simplistic and without support.
way to emphasize that nobody can know beforehand when that day, nor when that hour will arrive - what's your proof? Where are other verses? You just assert it as fact. And you didn't address when Jesus only used hour instead of day and hour

I suggest you stick with the Christianity Stack Exchange.

@Maximus1987 - please be kind and courteous - these comments are verging on rude and surly.  Anne is an experienced and respected user on this site and your comments amount to dismissive put-downs.
